# Showing a series converges to a function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have calculated the Taylor series for  $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ centered at $x=0$ with some help and have gotten the following,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$$,

I then found the values of $x$ for which the series converges, through the ratio test I found these values to be $-1<x<=1$. I am now trying to prove that the series converges to the function $ln(1+x)$ for these values of $x$ that I have found.

So how would I prove that it converges to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it might be instructive to show convergence using only the sum of a geometric progression and an elementary inequality.  To that end we proceed.

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}\int_0^xt^{n-1}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^N (-t)^{n-1}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^x\frac{1-(-t)^N}{1+t}\,dt\\\\
&=\log(1+x)-(-1)^N\int_0^x\frac{t^N}{1+t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Now, note that for $|x|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\left| \int_0^x\frac{t^N}{1+t}\,dt\right|&\le \frac{1}{1-|x|}\int_0^x t^n\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{x^{N+1}}{(1-|x|)(N+1)}\\\\
&\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Therefore, for $|x|<1$, we have

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}=\log(1+x)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

According to [Lagrange remainders](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html), we have

$$P_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}nx^n$$

For some $\xi\in(-1,1)$, we then have

$$\ln(1+x)-P_k(x)=\frac{\xi^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

But since $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\xi^{k+1}}{k+1}=0\forall\xi\in(-1,1)$, it follows that

$$\ln(1+x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}P_k(x)$$

At $x=1$, we can show convergence through the partial sums:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n&=\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1t^{n-1}\ dt\\&=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^{n+1}t^{n-1}\ dt\\\text{(geometric series)}&=\int_0^1\frac{1-(-t)^k}{1+t}\ dt\\&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+t}\ dt+(-1)^{k+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^k}{1+t}\ dt\\&=\ln(2)+(-1)^{k+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^k}{1+t}\ dt\end{align}$$

We can then squeeze the last integral, since:

$$0<\int_0^1\frac{t^k}{1+t}\ dt<\int_0^1t^k\ dt=\frac1{k+1}\stackrel{k\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

Comment: I don't understand where does that "we then have" come from *if* we don't assume beforehand what we want to prove, or something very similar...

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not quite sure what you are saying.  We could've let $\xi\in(a,b)$ and discovered what $a,b$ were afterwards.

Comment: so then I don't need to show for x=1? thanks for your submission btw

Comment: @Simly My point is: where does $\;\log(1+x)\;$ come from? Why after you define $\;P_k(x)\;$ and choose a point in $\;(-1,1)\;$ , all of a sudden appears there $\;\log(1+x)\;$ in that difference?

Comment: @fr14 I think one usually proves boundary cases separately.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it came from the question.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ok, upon reading more carefully the question I realize now the OP said *he calculated* the Taylor series of $\;\log(1+x)\;$ and etc., so that justifies using this function. I thought he asked how to show the series in its question converges to the logarithms *without knowing before hand* that's the Taylor series of the log.

Comment: @fr14 Note that you could also evaluate the partial sums of the series and take the limit as the upper bound goes to infinity.

Comment: @DonAntonio Haha, no problem.  As an aside, this is the third question in the series of questions the OP has posted today concerning this topic, so... I've kinda been watching the progress.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art this lat comment, that you could also evaluate the partial sums of the series and take the limit as the upper bound goes to infinity. would this show that my values of x would converge to the function?

Comment: @fr14 By definition, of course!

Comment: okay, so then how would I calculate all the partial sums when the x value is $-1<x<=1$?

Comment: @fr14 You only need to check $x=1$ since we know it converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges at $x=-1$, and I'm working on it.  It usually involves turning the series into some integral form or something like that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt okay thanks again

Comment: @fr14 No problem and done.

Answer (score 2):

Such series is the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ at the origin. The Taylor series is unique. The radius of convergence of the power series is one. $\log(1+x)$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin. It follows that
$$ \log(1+x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n \tag{1}$$
holds for any $x\in(-1,1)$. As an alternative, for any $z\in(-1,1)$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n z^n\tag{2} $$
hence by integrating both sides of $(2)$ over the interval $(0,x)$ we get $(1)$ for any $x\in(-1,1)$. We are allowed to exchange $\int$ and $\sum$ due to the absolute convergence of the RHS of $(2)$.

Comment: isn't the interval $(-1,1]$?

Comment: @fr14 Proving convergence at the boundaries is a tad harder.

Comment: Pointwise convergence is not ensured over the boundary of the disk of convergence. Abel's lemma grants that $(1)$ holds at $x=1$, too.

Comment: @fr14:the sequence $\{(-1)^{n+1}\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums and $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing towards zero.

Comment: wouldn't that be dirichlet test?

Comment: @fr14: they are strictly related. Abel's lemma gives that $(1)$ holds at $x=1$ because $\log(1+x)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $x=1$, but such statement ultimately boils down to applying Dirichlet's test to the series on the RHS.